# How to decompose square root SWAP gate in Mathematica

Tags: quantum-gate

The Quantum Mathematica add-on package is a very good tool to implement quantum gates. It contains gates as shown in this figure.

[image]

How to use these gates to decompose square root SWAP gate?

Comment: are you asking for a gate decomposition of the square root swap in terms of the gates listed in the figure, or are you asking how to write said gate in Mathematica in general? In the latter case, can't you simply do `swap=SparseArray@Thread[{{1,1}, {2,3}, {3,2}, {4,4}} -> 1]; MatrixFunction[Sqrt, swap]`?

Comment: @glS yes I want to decompose square root swap gate 
using the gates listed in the figure

Comment: so the question doesn't really have much to do with Mathematica..

Answer (score 1):

Why not use
$$
e^{i\pi/4}(I+i SWAP)/\sqrt{2}?
$$