# Implement a square root of Swap gate in using qiskit

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

Does the √SWAP gate have a ready-to-use function on the Qiskit circuit library?

If not, how to implement it?

Comment: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/how-to-implement-the-square-root-of-swap-gate-on-the-ibm-q-composer

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21708/55

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expressing "Square root of Swap" gate in terms of CNOT](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/expressing-square-root-of-swap-gate-in-terms-of-cnot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think √SWAP gate has a ready-to-use function in Qiskit. But it is easy to implement.

√SWAP unitary is:
$$\sqrt{swap} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&\frac{1}{2}(1 + i)&\frac{1}{2}(1 - i)&0 \\ 0&\frac{1}{2}(1 - i)&\frac{1}{2}(1 + i)&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{array}} \right)$$

It is equivalent to:

[image]

So, it can be implemented as follows:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.cx(0, 1)
circ.csx(1, 0)
circ.cx(0, 1)
```

To verify:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex

op = Operator(circ)
array_to_latex(op)
```

And to use it as a gate:

```
sr_swap = circ.to_gate(label = '√SWAP')

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.append(sr_swap, [0, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer. Is there a command that prints out the truth table for this circuit?